# Codeigniter jQuery File Upload Unexpected Token

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to implement [this](http://vortexdev.netii.net/article_20/Integrate_jQuery_File_Upload_with_CodeIgniter) tutorial, I believe I have done the exactly what it said in the tutorial. But I am getting this error after the download process seems to be finished.

> `Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Here you can see my controller:

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view("upload");
}

public function upload()
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);


    $this->load->helper("upload.class");

    $upload_handler = new UploadHandler();

    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="files.json"');
    header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-File-Name, X-File-Type, X-File-Size');

    switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        case 'OPTIONS':
            break;
        case 'HEAD':
        case 'GET':
            $upload_handler->get();
            break;
        case 'POST':
            if (isset($_REQUEST['_method']) && $_REQUEST['_method'] === 'DELETE') {
                $upload_handler->delete();
            } else {
                $upload_handler->post();
            }
            break;
        case 'DELETE':
            $upload_handler->delete();
            break;
        default:
            header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
    }
}
```

}

There is a class that makes all the upload stuff, which is put into helpers folder. I am suspecting that putting not functions but a class into helper folder can cause the problem? However, the error, I think, not related to this. Maybe the problem with the jQuery, but again not sure.

Here is the some portion of my view for you to check out:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="<?=base_url()?>upload/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="span7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress information -->
            <div class="span5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active">
                    <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress information -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
        <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
        <br>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
    </form>

<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
            <td>
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Load-Image/load-image.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS and Bootstrap Image Gallery are not required, but included for the demo -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload file processing plugin -->
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<!-- The localization script -->
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/locale.js"></script>
<!-- The main application script -->
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/main.js"></script>
```

Here is the upload class that is in my helper folder of Codeigniter:

```
    <?php

class UploadHandler
{
    protected $options;

    function __construct($options=null) {
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/',
            'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/files/',
            'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/files/',
            'param_name' => 'files',
            // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
            // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
            'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
            // The php.ini settings upload_max_filesize and post_max_size
            // take precedence over the following max_file_size setting:
            'max_file_size' => null,
            'min_file_size' => 1,
            'accept_file_types' => '/.+$/i',
            // The maximum number of files for the upload directory:
            'max_number_of_files' => null,
            // Image resolution restrictions:
            'max_width' => null,
            'max_height' => null,
            'min_width' => 1,
            'min_height' => 1,
            // Set the following option to false to enable resumable uploads:
            'discard_aborted_uploads' => true,
            // Set to true to rotate images based on EXIF meta data, if available:
            'orient_image' => false,
            'image_versions' => array(
                // Uncomment the following version to restrict the size of
                // uploaded images. You can also add additional versions with
                // their own upload directories:
                /*
                'large' => array(
                    'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/files/',
                    'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/files/',
                    'max_width' => 1920,
                    'max_height' => 1200,
                    'jpeg_quality' => 95
                ),
                */
                'thumbnail' => array(
                    'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/thumbnails/',
                    'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/thumbnails/',
                    'max_width' => 80,
                    'max_height' => 80
                )
            )
        );
        if ($options) {
            $this->options = array_replace_recursive($this->options, $options);
        }
    }

    protected function getFullUrl() {
        return
            (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://').
            (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].'@' : '').
            (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].
            (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] === 443 ||
            $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] === 80 ? '' : ':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']))).
            substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/'));
    }

    protected function set_file_delete_url($file) {
        $file->delete_url = $this->options['script_url']
            .'?file='.rawurlencode($file->name);
        $file->delete_type = $this->options['delete_type'];
        if ($file->delete_type !== 'DELETE') {
            $file->delete_url .= '&_method=DELETE';
        }
    }

    protected function get_file_object($file_name) {
        $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        if (is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.') {
            $file = new stdClass();
            $file->name = $file_name;
            $file->size = filesize($file_path);
            $file->url = $this->options['upload_url'].rawurlencode($file->name);
            foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                if (is_file($options['upload_dir'].$file_name)) {
                    $file->{$version.'_url'} = $options['upload_url']
                        .rawurlencode($file->name);
                }
            }
            $this->set_file_delete_url($file);
            return $file;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected function get_file_objects() {
        return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
            array($this, 'get_file_object'),
            scandir($this->options['upload_dir'])
        )));
    }

    protected function create_scaled_image($file_name, $options) {
        $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        $new_file_path = $options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($file_path);
        if (!$img_width || !$img_height) {
            return false;
        }
        $scale = min(
            $options['max_width'] / $img_width,
            $options['max_height'] / $img_height
        );
        if ($scale >= 1) {
            if ($file_path !== $new_file_path) {
                return copy($file_path, $new_file_path);
            }
            return true;
        }
        $new_width = $img_width * $scale;
        $new_height = $img_height * $scale;
        $new_img = @imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        switch (strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                $src_img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
                $write_image = 'imagejpeg';
                $image_quality = isset($options['jpeg_quality']) ?
                    $options['jpeg_quality'] : 75;
                break;
            case 'gif':
                @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
                $src_img = @imagecreatefromgif($file_path);
                $write_image = 'imagegif';
                $image_quality = null;
                break;
            case 'png':
                @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
                @imagealphablending($new_img, false);
                @imagesavealpha($new_img, true);
                $src_img = @imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
                $write_image = 'imagepng';
                $image_quality = isset($options['png_quality']) ?
                    $options['png_quality'] : 9;
                break;
            default:
                $src_img = null;
        }
        $success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
            $new_img,
            $src_img,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            $new_width,
            $new_height,
            $img_width,
            $img_height
        ) && $write_image($new_img, $new_file_path, $image_quality);
        // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
        @imagedestroy($src_img);
        @imagedestroy($new_img);
        return $success;
    }

    protected function validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index) {
        if ($error) {
            $file->error = $error;
            return false;
        }
        if (!$file->name) {
            $file->error = 'missingFileName';
            return false;
        }
        if (!preg_match($this->options['accept_file_types'], $file->name)) {
            $file->error = 'acceptFileTypes';
            return false;
        }
        if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
            $file_size = filesize($uploaded_file);
        } else {
            $file_size = $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
        }
        if ($this->options['max_file_size'] && (
                $file_size > $this->options['max_file_size'] ||
                $file->size > $this->options['max_file_size'])
            ) {
            $file->error = 'maxFileSize';
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->options['min_file_size'] &&
            $file_size < $this->options['min_file_size']) {
            $file->error = 'minFileSize';
            return false;
        }
        if (is_int($this->options['max_number_of_files']) && (
                count($this->get_file_objects()) >= $this->options['max_number_of_files'])
            ) {
            $file->error = 'maxNumberOfFiles';
            return false;
        }
        list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($uploaded_file);
        if (is_int($img_width)) {
            if ($this->options['max_width'] && $img_width > $this->options['max_width'] ||
                    $this->options['max_height'] && $img_height > $this->options['max_height']) {
                $file->error = 'maxResolution';
                return false;
            }
            if ($this->options['min_width'] && $img_width < $this->options['min_width'] ||
                    $this->options['min_height'] && $img_height < $this->options['min_height']) {
                $file->error = 'minResolution';
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function upcount_name_callback($matches) {
        $index = isset($matches[1]) ? intval($matches[1]) + 1 : 1;
        $ext = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : '';
        return ' ('.$index.')'.$ext;
    }

    protected function upcount_name($name) {
        return preg_replace_callback(
            '/(?:(?: \(([\d]+)\))?(\.[^.]+))?$/',
            array($this, 'upcount_name_callback'),
            $name,
            1
        );
    }

    protected function trim_file_name($name, $type, $index) {
        // Remove path information and dots around the filename, to prevent uploading
        // into different directories or replacing hidden system files.
        // Also remove control characters and spaces (\x00..\x20) around the filename:
        $file_name = trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");
        // Add missing file extension for known image types:
        if (strpos($file_name, '.') === false &&
            preg_match('/^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)/', $type, $matches)) {
            $file_name .= '.'.$matches[1];
        }
        if ($this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
            while(is_file($this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name)) {
                $file_name = $this->upcount_name($file_name);
            }
        }
        return $file_name;
    }

    protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
        // Handle form data, e.g. $_REQUEST['description'][$index]
    }

    protected function orient_image($file_path) {
        $exif = @exif_read_data($file_path);
        if ($exif === false) {
            return false;
        }
        $orientation = intval(@$exif['Orientation']);
        if (!in_array($orientation, array(3, 6, 8))) { 
            return false;
        }
        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
        switch ($orientation) {
              case 3:
                $image = @imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
                break;
              case 6:
                $image = @imagerotate($image, 270, 0);
                break;
              case 8:
                $image = @imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        $success = imagejpeg($image, $file_path);
        // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
        @imagedestroy($image);
        return $success;
    }

    protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index) {
        $file = new stdClass();
        $file->name = $this->trim_file_name($name, $type, $index);
        $file->size = intval($size);
        $file->type = $type;
        if ($this->validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index)) {
            $this->handle_form_data($file, $index);
            $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file->name;
            $append_file = !$this->options['discard_aborted_uploads'] &&
                is_file($file_path) && $file->size > filesize($file_path);
            clearstatcache();
            if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
                // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
                if ($append_file) {
                    file_put_contents(
                        $file_path,
                        fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                        FILE_APPEND
                    );
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
                }
            } else {
                // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                    $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
                );
            }
            $file_size = filesize($file_path);
            if ($file_size === $file->size) {
                if ($this->options['orient_image']) {
                    $this->orient_image($file_path);
                }
                $file->url = $this->options['upload_url'].rawurlencode($file->name);
                foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                    if ($this->create_scaled_image($file->name, $options)) {
                        if ($this->options['upload_dir'] !== $options['upload_dir']) {
                            $file->{$version.'_url'} = $options['upload_url']
                                .rawurlencode($file->name);
                        } else {
                            clearstatcache();
                            $file_size = filesize($file_path);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if ($this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
                unlink($file_path);
                $file->error = 'abort';
            }
            $file->size = $file_size;
            $this->set_file_delete_url($file);
        }
        return $file;
    }

    public function get() {
        $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
            basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
        if ($file_name) {
            $info = $this->get_file_object($file_name);
        } else {
            $info = $this->get_file_objects();
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($info);
    }

    public function post() {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['_method']) && $_REQUEST['_method'] === 'DELETE') {
            return $this->delete();
        }
        $upload = isset($_FILES[$this->options['param_name']]) ?
            $_FILES[$this->options['param_name']] : null;
        $info = array();
        if ($upload && is_array($upload['tmp_name'])) {
            // param_name is an array identifier like "files[]",
            // $_FILES is a multi-dimensional array:
            foreach ($upload['tmp_name'] as $index => $value) {
                $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                    $upload['tmp_name'][$index],
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ?
                        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : $upload['name'][$index],
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']) ?
                        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'] : $upload['size'][$index],
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']) ?
                        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'] : $upload['type'][$index],
                    $upload['error'][$index],
                    $index
                );
            }
        } elseif ($upload || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'])) {
            // param_name is a single object identifier like "file",
            // $_FILES is a one-dimensional array:
            $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                isset($upload['tmp_name']) ? $upload['tmp_name'] : null,
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : (isset($upload['name']) ?
                        $upload['name'] : null),
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'] : (isset($upload['size']) ?
                        $upload['size'] : null),
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'] : (isset($upload['type']) ?
                        $upload['type'] : null),
                isset($upload['error']) ? $upload['error'] : null
            );
        }
        header('Vary: Accept');
        $json = json_encode($info);
        $redirect = isset($_REQUEST['redirect']) ?
            stripslashes($_REQUEST['redirect']) : null;
        if ($redirect) {
            header('Location: '.sprintf($redirect, rawurlencode($json)));
            return;
        }
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) &&
            (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/json') !== false)) {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
        } else {
            header('Content-type: text/plain');
        }
        echo $json;
    }

    public function delete() {
        $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
            basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
        $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        $success = is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.' && unlink($file_path);
        if ($success) {
            foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                $file = $options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
                if (is_file($file)) {
                    unlink($file);
                }
            }
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($success);
    }

}
```

Any idea, any help will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the error a PHP error or a javascript error?

Comment: Not sure of that, the error is given on the view and most probably resulted from javascript. You can try the demo from here: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ this one is working but in my implementation above, after the upload finished there is the error comes out where the normally progress bar is placed.

Comment: Well 1. you are missing the break statement in your default: in the switch statement. Can you post the class that does the upload stuff that you're talking about?

Comment: Just added the upload class and I dont think last break should not be a big issue yet going to put that thing anyway.

Comment: hmm, I don't spot any out of place greater than signs. I wish PHP gave you the line number the error happened around. Are you sure that's the entire error message that you're receiving?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20717/discussion-between-jay-and-magicmarkker)

Answer (score 0):

You are not suposed to load classes as [helpers](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html):

> Unlike most other systems in CodeIgniter, Helpers are not written in
>   an Object Oriented format. They are simple, procedural functions. Each
>   helper function performs one specific task, with no dependence on
>   other functions.

For that feature there are [libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/libraries.html):

> When we use the term "Libraries" we are normally referring to the
>   classes that are located in the libraries directory and described in
>   the Class Reference of this user guide. In this case, however, we will
>   instead describe how you can create your own libraries within your
>   application/libraries directory in order to maintain separation
>   between your local resources and the global framework resources.

When you manually load with `$this->load->helper()` or put it in the config array of `autoload.php` what CodeIgniter is doing is just going to the helpers folder of your application folder and doing an `include_once` nothing more.

As for the libraries it is the same thing, but with the difference that CI will make an instance of your library class object and attach it to it's current instance, that is, the main CodeIgniter application instance, the one that you can access with `get_instance()`

That being said, what you are getting is a common issue when you are expecting an object such as a json response from the server but instead you get some sort of html output, that, in this case, must be the codeigniter error page. That's why you see the `Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` becaue the html tag starts with that sign.

Open up firefox or chrome developer tools and debug the server response, on the response you should be able to see the content (if any) of CodeIgniter which will be the error page and the error description, that is of course, if you have the environment set to display such errors.

See [this other response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614951/can-i-change-codeigniter-show-error-function-to-return-json-object/21786593#21786593) I have here to know how to debug your error.